# Convert PHP Two-dimensional Arrays to PHP Extension

Tags: php, c, php-extension

How can I read multidimensional array in PHP extension?

```
$dataValue[0][1] = 'a';
$dataValue[0][2] = 'b';
```

And here is my PHP extension code:

```
ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_BUCKET(Z_ARRVAL_P(data_r_value), Bucket *bucket)
    setArray(&bucket, currentRow, currentCol, dataValue[currentRow][currentCol]);
ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();
```

I'm tried to use `dataValue[currentRow][currentCol]` to read value but it gives an error:

> '[': illegal for struct

Thank in advance.

Comment: I have no idea how c works but is `dataValue` within scope?

Comment: `php_array_merge_recursive` from https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/001d43444944df0bef4e33a1876ba2818c188e11/ext/standard/array.c could have some hints

Comment: You're trying to convert a C two dimensional array to a php two dimensional array?

Comment: @Nina I'm trying convert PHP 2 dimensional array to C. To make a PHP extension.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Here is my code in the picture: https://i.imgur.com/14Q0bkI.png

Comment: @HVD Sorry, I am not familiar with C :-/

Comment: Are you sending the data from PHP across a network or just doing it in your C code?

Comment: @Nina I'm making PHP extension. I'm sending data from PHP to C Extension.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem by using 2 for loop.

PHP Array:

```
$data[0][1] = 'a'; // $data[x][y], x: row, y: col
```

In C, PHP Extension:

```
zend_bool found = FALSE;
zend_long iRow;
zend_string *sRow;
zval *rowArray;
ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL(Z_ARRVAL_P(format_handle), iRow, sRow, rowArray)
    if (iRow == rowNeeded) {
        zend_long iCol;
        zend_string *sCol;
        zval *formatData;
        ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_KEY_VAL(Z_ARRVAL_P(rowArray), iCol, sCol, formatData)
            if (iCol == colNeeded) {
               found = TRUE;
               break;
            }
        ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();
     }
     if (found) { break; }
ZEND_HASH_FOREACH_END();
```